# GitHub, define language for unknown suffix?

Tags: github, github-linguist

I have a repository that has Python source code in it, but the files are suffixed `*.pyp`. Is there a way to "assign it" to the Python language? (shown in tags, syntax highlighting, etc.)

I thought I saw something like this possible in the `.gitattributes` file..

Comment: Here is the answer to the same question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31654/force-github-syntax-highlighting-language-on-source-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I saw something like this possible in the `.gitattributes` file..

Yes, this is possible using [Linguist overrides](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides). You'd want:

```
*.pyp linguist-language=Python
```

However, `.pyp` is recognized by Linguist [since June 2014](https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/1258) (after your question's date).

Answer (score 1):

For files with a [**Shebang**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29),
the Shebang is considered when determining the language but seems to be evenly
weighted against other
[**tokens**](http://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/samples.json).
This seems to be a big error because the Shebang should definitively define the
language of the file. This can cause [**issues**](http://github.com/github/linguist/issues/281) with highlighting.

As a workaround you can add dummy tokens in the form of a comment to "tip the scales" in favor of the correct language. This is experimental but I have [**had luck with it**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.cygwin#l2).